# Getting Error: return statement is missing in switch statement

Tags: c#-3.0

I thought my switch case was written correctly but I got an error:

> return statement is missing in the last bracket.

Please find below my code:

```
    public  string  getUrl(string code )   
    {
        switch (code)

        {

          case  "1": 
              return "#";
          case "2":
              return "#";
          case "3": 
              return "#";
          case "4":
              return "#";
          case "5": 
              return "#";
          case "6": 
              return "#";
          case "7": 
              return "#";


        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is a `default` case. What `string` should this function return if none of the cases you mentioned occur.

e.g. I pass `"unknown"` to this method `getUrl`.

So just add a `default` case and things should work fine.

The code should look something like

```
    public  string  getUrl(string code )   
    {
        switch (code)

        {

          case  "1": 
              return "#";
          case "2":
              return "#";
          case "3": 
              return "#";
          case "4":
              return "#";
          case "5": 
              return "#";
          case "6": 
              return "#";
          case "7": 
              return "#";
          default:
              return "Unknown case occured!";

        }

    }
```